# Annotate individually each item in a Django Queryset

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

## Objective

I'm trying to get a queryset that tells me if a user is subscribed to a given mailing list and being able to access that bool using mailing_list.is_subbed

Ideally we would have a queryset where each item has a annotated field "is_subbed" which is either `True` or `False`.

## Context

For context, this view is going to serve a form with checkboxes that are checked/unchecked depending on the status of the user.
The page is accessible in incognito mode through a url that holds a token which contains 1) The email of the user and 2) The ID of the mail send record (which holds details like the mailing list it's been sent to, details below)

## Question

In the current state, the `is_subbed` function is called only once on the first item, and the resulting bool is annotated to every item, I'd like it to run for each item in the queryset.
How can I do that ? For now if the first item returns `True` once fed to `is_subbed`, every checkbox is marked because the annotated field `is_subbed` is set to True on each item.

## Code

Here is my current work :
Summary :

1. The view
2. Implementation of function and models used in said view
3. Snippet I use to access my results in jinja2

`views.py`

```py
class PressSubscriptionManagementView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "mailing_list/press_subscription_management.html"

    def is_subbed(self, user: User, mailing_list: MailingList) -> bool:
        """
        Check if the user is subbed to the mailing list
        """
        return user_current_state(user, mailing_list).event_type == "sub"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) -> dict:
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        email, send_record_id = token_valid(kwargs["token"])
        if email and send_record_id:
            context["user"] = User.objects.get(email=email)
            # In the current state, is_subbed is only called once on the first
            # item in the list. If this call returns True, every checkbox is
            # checked. None otherwise.
            context["press_subscription_list"] = \
                    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) -> dict:
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        email, send_record_id = token_valid(kwargs["token"])
        if email and send_record_id:
            context["user"] = User.objects.get(email=email)
            # In the current state, is_subbed is only called once on the first
            # item in the list. If this call returns True, every checkbox is
            # checked. None otherwise.
            context["press_subscription_list"] = \
                MailingList.objects.filter(
                    mailing_list_type="PR"
                    ).order_by("-id"
                    ).annotate(  # noqa
                        is_subbed=(
                            ExpressionWrapper(
                                Value(
                                    self.is_subbed(
                                        context["user"],
                                        F('mailing_list__id')
                                    ),
                                    output_field=BooleanField()
                                    ),
                                output_field=BooleanField()
                            )
                        )
                    )

        return context
```

implementation of user_current_state :

```py
def user_current_state(user, mailing_list):
    """Return user's most current state on the provided mailing list

    Return the most recent event associated with this user in this
    mailing list.

    """
    try:
        the_user = MailingListEvent.objects.filter(
            Q(event_type=MailingListEvent.EventType.SUBSCRIBE) |
            Q(event_type=MailingListEvent.EventType.UNSUBSCRIBE),
            user=user, mailing_list=mailing_list).latest(
                'event_timestamp')
        return the_user
    except MailingListEvent.DoesNotExist:
        return MailingListEvent(
            user=user, mailing_list=mailing_list,
            event_type=MailingListEvent.EventType.UNSUBSCRIBE)
```

Implementation of MailingList and MailingListEvent :

```py
class MailingListEvent(models.Model):

    class EventType(models.TextChoices):
        SUBSCRIBE = 'sub', 'inscription'
        UNSUBSCRIBE = 'unsub', 'désinscription'

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mailing_list = models.ForeignKey(MailingList,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class MailingList(models.Model):
    # This is a user-visible name that can change.
    mailing_list_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False)
    # This is the unique name that can't change.  It just makes code a
    # bit more readable than referring to the pk id.
    mailing_list_token = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False,
                                          unique=True)
```

And Finally the implementation of SendRecord :

```py
class TopicBlogEmailSendRecord(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=90, allow_unicode=True, blank=True)
    mailinglist = models.ForeignKey(MailingList, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

In the template, I access the value like this :

```
{% for mailing_list in press_subscription_list %}
    [...]
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ mailing_list.mailing_list_name }}"
    value="{{ mailing_list.id }}" id="mailing_list_id_{{ mailing_list.id }}"
    {% if mailing_list.is_subbed %} checked {% endif %} />
    [...]
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your `MailingListEvent` doesn't define an `event_type` field. I assume this got lost when copy-pasting?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `is_subbed()` method, you could use a [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions), combined with a [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case).

For example, something like this:

```py
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) -> dict:
    ...
    # subquery mailing list events for each of the user's mailing lists
    events = MailingListEvent.objects.filter(
        user=context['user'], mailing_list=models.OuterRef('pk')
    ).order_by('-event_timestamp')
    # annotate using subquery
    annotated_mailing_lists = MailingList.objects.annotate(
        latest_event_type=models.Subquery(events.values('event_type')[:1]),
        is_subbed=models.Case(
            models.When(latest_event_type='sub', then=True),
            default=False,
            output_field=models.BooleanField(),
        )
    )
    context["press_subscription_list"] = annotated_mailing_lists.filter(...)...
```

Notes:

- This assumes your `MailingListEvent` model defines `event_type` and `event_timestamp` fields (which are missing from your example).
- For clarity, I used `When(latest_event_type='sub', ...`, but you should probably use `MailingListEvent.EventType.SUBSCRIBE` instead of `'sub'`.